# Store Locator Module suitable for mobile

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, module, extensions, third-party-module

We have +3000 store locations to show on a map.

The store locator module we are using right now works fine on a desktop view, but when we open it on a phone it's taking between 40 seconds to 2 minutes to load the map and place the markers. We tried customizing it, to avoid placing the markers on the initial load, and show them only on performing a search, but the speed is still a problem.

In this case the issue seems to be with the amount of Javascript code that needs to be executed. Newer phones are getting better response times (under a minute for iPhone 6S), but older ones are taking close to 2 minutes.

Is there any recommendation for a store locator module with a +3000 stores database that works fine on a mobile device?

Comment: Please provide Magento 1 or 2 with it's Version. So can guide you

Comment: Hi Mike, we are currently using Magento 1.9 Community Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Maxmind GeoIP javascript API.
You can json encode your store location data.
You can serve a store page instead of a map using latitude and longitude returned by GeoIP.
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city

You can add the Google API to try to optimize for local search.

Comment: Thank you Lucas, I appreciate the suggestion, but unfortunately we don't have time to code it ourselves

Comment: I know, coding takes time. I've spent over a month with Magestore, and even paid for some customization. If anything, I recommend you to not use Magestore.

Comment: That's exactly the same experience we had with this vendor, and the main reason I'm asking the community for help. Thanks again

Comment: @JPlana we should collaborate on a store locator. I have similar work done in other frameworks, and some work started in Magento.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose from below mentioned [Magento 2 store locator](https://store.webkul.com/magento2-store-locator.html) extension providers

- https://amasty.com/magento-store-locator.html
- http://www.magestore.com/magento-store-locator-extension.html
- https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/store-locator.html

They are providing demo you can double check with them before buying.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the suggestion. I know about this solutions, but I was wondering if anyone has a similar setup +3000 stores and tried any of these extensions, so they can confirm they work fine with these volume of stores.

Comment: @JPlana as i mentioned please double check with extension provider. So they can check for load testing as per your requirement. I hope you will get solution

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mike. I will contact different vendors to see if they can help me.

Comment: @JPlana You most welcome. Happy to help